# Is it possible to implement arrayToList function in JS not from stepping through the array backwards?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) //How to implement it if i = 0?
    list = {
      value: array[i],
      rest: list
    };
  return list;
}
```

arr.reverse - not offer. I'm curious how it can be done if we're stepping through the array from array[0]? Or this task in JS only can be done if we're stepping through the array backwards?

Comment: do you want to step from the beginning and build a linked list?

Comment: Yes! @ Nina Scholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use two separate pointers for the list head and for the current node:

```js
function arrayToList(a) {
    var list = {}, p = list;
    for (let x of a) {
        p.value = x;
        p.rest = {};
        p = p.rest;
    }
    return list;
}


console.log(arrayToList([11,22,33]))
```

To nullify the last pointer you're going to need three pointers:

```
function arrayToList(a) {
    var list = {}, p = list, q;
    for (let x of a) {
        p.value = x;
        p.rest = {};
        q = p;
        p = p.rest;
    }
    q.rest = null;
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! How elegant to close list? I mean set the last element to null (tail).

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce an object and assign at the end `null`.

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = {};
    array.reduce((o, v, i, a) => (o.value = v, o.rest = i + 1 === a.length ? null : {}), list);
    return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([4, 5, 6, 7]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without a loop, using recursion instead.

```js
function arrayToListRecursive(arr) {
  return (!arr.length)
    ? null
    : {
        value: arr[0],
        rest: arrayToListRecursive(arr.slice(1))
      }
}


function arrayToListLoop(arr) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    list = { value: arr[arr.length - i], rest: list };
  }
  return list
}

console.log(
  arrayToListRecursive([1, 2, 3, 4])
)

console.log(
  arrayToListLoop([1, 2, 3, 4])
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! But if it would be a large array (10 million numbers) i think it would blow up stack.

Comment: fair comment, I have added a loop version, but I'm not sure you should be creating a list with 10 million numbers, there is probably a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: I've tested out your recursive version arrayToList, it can  process array on 18000 elements before stack blows up (on PC with 8gb memory), while loop version can  easy process array on 10000000 elemens.   @synthet1c